# Opencv minMaxLoc dont work properly

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to get local(size(3,3)) corr value matrix with possible shift ±2 pixels but the result (dst mat in code) when i compere two identical picture (refROI and srcROI get roi from the same picture) is not correct. First it has last ~100 right pixels at left side and the second is show in some point corr ~ 0 (should be 1 everywhere). Similarity also should by always 1 and what is more stange sometimes is has 0.0078125 but Min and max has 1.There is the code:

```
  double similarity=0,Min=0,Max=0;
        int count=0;
        int size=3,shiftSize=3;
        int width,height;
        width = floor(ref->colorMat.cols/size);
        height = floor(ref->colorMat.rows/size);
        Mat dst= Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC1);
        for(int i=shiftSize;i<width-shiftSize;i++){
            for(int j=shiftSize;j<height-shiftSize;j++){
                Mat result,refROI,srcROI;
                refROI = ref->colorMat(Rect(j*size-shiftSize,i*size-shiftSize,size+2*shiftSize,size+2*shiftSize));
                srcROI =  ref->colorMat(Rect(j*size,i*size,size,size));
                count++;
                qDebug()<<count<<"Min: "<<Min<<"Max: "<<Max<< "similarity: "<<similarity;
                matchTemplate(refROI, srcROI, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
                similarity = result.at<double>(shiftSize,shiftSize);
                minMaxLoc(result,&Min,&Max);
                dst.at<double>(i,j)=Max;
            }
        }
        normalize( dst, dst, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
        Mat sss;
        dst.copyTo(sss);
        imshow("sss",sss);
```

[compare result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmFmn.png)
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCRyZ.png)

Comment: I do not see a problem with min max, but with your code in general.... you try to match a template, and then you just get the value in position (3,3) and then compare it to the max? an you do this for all the image? first of all, matchTemplate already searches all the image, the for loop is not necessary, secondly in this case the max location is the best match found. Take a look to this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) to understand how to use template matching in opencv.

Comment: I look at the value at 3,3 becouse there should be the best match, I do this in loops for get correlation in rect (3,3) (im looking for local difference between two images) and i save it to mat to find the locations where two images in small area are diffrent - I want to use it to find small defects

Comment: Oh, ok then it makes sense. Are you comparing the normalized values (dst variable) or min max values directly with the similarity?

Comment: similarity is no use, I need it only for check if all works correctly, this is the point where templete maching compare two the same parts of image so it should give 100% correlation (when compare the same two images). Min Max should have the min max correlation (and max should always be 1 - there are 2 the same images) and similarity should be between this values but it doesn't. Probably you are right in the part that the problem is in my code but I watch it an hours and I dont see it

Comment: well, first, put qdebug after the minMaxLoc function. Then you can compare the debug info to see if they differ (max and similarity)

Comment: You are right but i get both (max and similarity) from last compute so I will get the same output (without fist and last). I added photo with part of consol output.

Comment: similarity = result.at<float>(shiftSize,shiftSize);
I change double to float and now it has the same value as Max but still result mat isn't whole in white (looks like the one I added).

Comment: when I change also this part // dst.at<float>(i,j)=similarity; // from double to float the algorithm has begun working properly ! ;) Thanks api55 for help! I have last question, thah was my first post here so i should delete this post or leave it as it is?

Comment: you can leave it here. If you have a solution post it as an answer, other people with similar problems may need this answer in the future